# How to normalise data in Hdf5 data format

Tags: python, time-series, normalization, median, standard-deviation

I am trying to normalize all the data inside an hdf5 file format. I am trying to extract the vectors from the file and normalize the data. I would like to know the optimal way to normalize data. The data in the H5 file is a time series dataset.

```
with h5py.File('./test.h5','r') as f:
    for team in f:
        freq = f[team]['fs'][...]
        timestamps = f[team]['time'][...]
        amplitude = f[team]['amp'][...]
        freq_mean = np.mean(freq.values())
        freq_std = np.std(freq.values)
        freq_norm = (f[team]['fs'] - freq_mean)/freq_std
        print(freq)
        print(freq_norm)
```

The structure of the datasets is as shown here

```
with h5py.File('./test.h5','r') as hdf:
    boo = hdf.get('B00')
    boo_items = list(boo.items())
    print(boo_items)

[('amp', <HDF5 group "/B00/amp" (3 members)>),  ('fs', <HDF5 dataset "freqaxis": shape (2592,), type "|S32">), ('freqs', <HDF5 dataset "freqs": shape (3,), type "|S4">), , ('time', <HDF5 dataset "time": shape (69,), type "|S5">)]
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to normalize the entire dataset just in case.

Comment: By normalize do you mean freq.values()/freq_mean ?

Comment: freqnorm = (hdf5_file["vector"] - freq_mean) / freq_std which is essentially frequwncuy value subtracted by mean and divided by standard deviation value.

Comment: I think I can consider np.mean(freq) here instead of freq.values()